# Material-UI download icon

Tags: material-ui

Do you know if material UI has something like [download icon](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=download+icon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I could not find it by name download or export. Is it really missing or it is just has some other name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import GetAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/GetApp';
```

[Here](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/) you can search for more material-ui icons